# Apple Watch 3 is not charging fully

Tags: apple-watch

I have an Apple Watch 3 GPS model. Starting from this week, it is not charging fully.

After a night of charging, it is only something like 95%

Is that normal? Or is it a defect? It was always charging to 100%

Comment: Are you using the charger and cable that came with the Watch or from a 3rd party?

Comment: @fsb I am using the one that comes with watch itself. I don’t use 3rd party chargers in general

Comment: Do you have any other charger and cable you can use?  This would eliminate the possibility that one of those is faulty and it's a much easier fix.  If not, and the Watch is still under warranty, you could take it back to be replaced.  I have a Watch 2 and I get 100% battery after a few hours of charging.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Apple Watch series 3 (I have the LTE model)
No matter how long I charged it, it capped at 94%. So I did a simple hard reset (hold down on the side button and the crown for at least 10 seconds or until the apple logo comes up) and that seemed to fix my problem. I think it is a glitch from the most recent watchOS.